# Android Set view to be 20 px to the left of the containing view so its partially covered

Tags: android, layout, android-framelayout

I would like to cut off 20px from the left hand edge of my WebView.  I can not do this inside the WebView therefore I thought i could have the WebView 20px wider than the containing view, and then simply lay it out so its 20px left of the containing view therefore blocking off this 20px on the left hand side.

They say a picture speaks a thousand words, so hopefully this diagram illustrates what I am trying to do.

[image]

I have a WebView inside a FrameLayout and my WebView's width is 20px wider than its parent view.  How can I now position the WebView to the left 20px inside the FrameLayout?

I can not use RelativeLayout as when i do it appears to make my WebView the SAME width as the RelativeLayout which is not what I want as if i then moved it 20px left, there would be a 20px gap on the right hand side.

**My Layout Code**

The image contains the layout code I am using, where the "..." replace values which does not affect the WebView's placement inside the main view (such as id/background color etc). Below is my layout in more detail in case I am missing something.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_container"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="4dp"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/my_webview"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

I have tried changing the WebView to the following (addition marginLeft parameter) but it does not move the WebView to the left

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/my_webview"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-20px"/>
```

Comment: `android:marginLeft="-20px"` ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try `-ve` margin

```
  <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-20px"></WebView>
```

Comment: Sorry i should have included what I have tried.  The marginLeft was my first thought, but it doesn't actually move the WebView itself

Comment: Sorry, I realise now the layout code I put in the image is too vague. I have edited my question to include my actual layout